# Twilio client WebRTC not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jsp, twilio

I am using Twilio Client softphone in my application and it is working fine on my local system for both inbound and outbound call but when I deployed it on Server (AWS ec2 instance) always I am getting below error on chrome for inbound and outbound call.

```
getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See (google url) for more details.
```

I am including twilio.min.js in following manner.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.4/taskrouter.min.js"></script>
```

You can see I am including js file by using HTTPS. Even after that I have downloaded twilio.min.js file and added in local directory and included js file by using local directory also but still getting the same error.
So how can I solve this issue.

Comment: TokBox explains the issue in this blog post very well: http://www.tokbox.com/blog/the-impact-of-googles-new-chrome-security-policy-on-webrtc/

Answer (score 3):

The getUserMedia API requires you to use HTTPS on your site in Chrome (i.e. the script that executes getUserMedia). That has been the case for quite a while, see [here](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/the-impact-of-googles-new-chrome-security-policy-on-webrtc/) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you give me an example how I can use this API. My website url is started as http://<IP>:<host> does that matter? or I need to use https:// , one more thing in twilio documentation not mention that you need this API so I am getting confused on this.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js

> You should use HTTPS to serve your page. Starting with Google Chrome
>   47, HTTP applications will no longer be allowed to call getUserMedia()
>   and will not be given access to the user's camera and microphone.

Comment: Use HTTPS means my whole application should run on HTTPS port? or only I need to include twilio and other libraries from HTTPS cdn?

Comment: Your entire application should use HTTPS.

Comment: My entire application now using to HTTPS port but still I am not able to make a call from chrome browser as well as firefox. In console shows **opening socket, socket opened** message but when I make a outboud call in console get **[Connection] Received HANGUP from gateway** message, can you please suggest me how can I solve this issue.

Comment: That's a new error at least! It would probably be best if you send those logs to support: twilio.com/help/contact and we'll assist you from there.